# how to compare Radio Button value to string using RadioGroup

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist

i m creating app in which i m taking Radio Button Value From RadioGroup 
when i m Comparing the Value in if Statement it is not working. Here is Java code that i m using.

```
if(radioQuizeGroup.getText() == "History"){
    Log.d("History", "Activity");
    Toast.makeText(StartQuize.this,"History sss ss ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
else{
    Log.d("History", "Error ");
}
```

and i m getting Error in Error log,
here is Error Log

```
01-05 07:15:02.885: D/gralloc_goldfish(2035): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-05 07:15:04.165: I/Choreographer(2035): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-05 07:15:05.245: D/dalvikvm(2035): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 5% free 3139K/3280K, paused 18ms, total 32ms
01-05 07:15:15.236: D/History(2035): Error
```

Please  Help me

Comment: you won't get an error (if the radiogroup isn't null) your message should be show in the debug loglevel. have you debug your code?

Comment: i not found getText() with radio group

Comment: logcate updated, Please check @ Manu Zi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended to use

```
if(radioQuizeGroup.getText().equals("History"))
```

rather than

```
if(radioQuizeGroup.getText() == "History")
```

Since the **`==` compares the location of the objects** and **`.equals()` compares the value of the objects**

Comment: Putting history first will also protect the code against NPE is getText returns null.

Comment: @R9J can u please tell me how to open a new box  Area after selecting a Radio box where you can place a EditBox to enter Numbers
help will appreciate

Comment: @AshuKumar You can call a new Activity when option is clicked

Comment: but i donot want to see a New Screen , is there a any way to swho new Activity in Existing Activity ?

Comment: Then use `PopupWindow`, for more http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285

Answer (score 2):

Never compare String using the `==` operator, use the `equals` method instead :

```
if("History".equals(radioQuizeGroup.getText())){
    Log.d("History", "Activity");
    Toast.makeText(StartQuize.this, "History sss ss ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Log.d("History", "Error ");
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) has a nice answer that explains this a bit more.

Of course this assumes `radioQuizeGroup` is actually a widget that has a `getText` method as `RadioGroup` doesn't...

Comment: can u please tell me how to open a new box Area after selecting a Radio box where you can place a EditBox to enter Numbers help will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I would check, by using the selected item id like below

```
int selectedId = radioQuizeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if(selectedId == RadioButton1.getId()) //Id of the RadioButton1
 {
 //do something here
 } 
 else 
{
 //else do something here
 }
```